# Django Compressor - COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD not working

Tags: django-compressor

I would like to get the css file name unchanged after turning less file into css, and compression. All is managed by Django Compressor 2.1.

The problem is that I get this kind of file name with a hash :

```
1fa59c298fb5.css
```

But I would like to keep the original file name, like so :

```
style.css
```

Here is my configuration in settings.py Django (1.9.11):

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = ['compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter']
COMPRESS_JS_FILTERS = []
COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD = None
```

I don't understang why `COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD` to `None` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The `CssAbsoluteFilter` turns relative urls in your css into absolute ones. While doing that, it appends a hash to those urls to help with cache busting. that hash is determined by `COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD` and omitted when that setting is None.

So this has nothing to do with any filename at all :) In the output file you usually want a hash since cache busting is actually important there. Since the compress tag is most likely most often applied to multiple files, "keeping the original filename" doesn't really apply because there are multiple files contained in there.

By pure chance there's a PR open right now to make the output filename configurable: https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/pull/861/files This will probably be merged in the next few days. You can use that branch of the PR already, or wait for the merge and use the develop branch, or wait for a release (which might take a while :) )

Comment: My mistake, for not having understood correctly the setting COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD. This PR is interresting ! Thank you. But I don't think it solves my issue. My aim is the to get the full path (including file name) of the compiled and compressed less file to set it in CKEditor. I was about to install gulp just for that. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: looking at https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/blob/develop/compressor/base.py#L90 (which gets called for all final output files as far as i can see), getting a fixed filename doesn't seem to be possible.